# MySQL count rows include zero (so close to what I want!)

Tags: mysql, join, count

I know I'm close and it is KILLING me. Need a fresh set of eyes here...

```
SELECT 
first_name, 
COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT first_name, job_status FROM typesetting 
LEFT JOIN employees ON typesetting.employees_id = employees.id 
LEFT JOIN job_status ON typesetting.job_status_id = job_status.id 
WHERE job_status NOT LIKE 'Archived' 
ORDER BY first_name ASC) 
AS CNT 
GROUP BY first_name
```

This gets me:

- Arnold (5)
- Claudia (19)
- Janet (29)
- Rich (21)
- Tom (4)
- Unassigned (24)

However, there are some results with zero values in there that I desperately want in the results, like this:

- Arnold (5)
- Cheryl (0)
- Claudia (19)
- Cyndi (0)
- Janet (29)
- Phil (0)
- Rich (21)
- Tom (4)
- Unassigned (24)

What am I doing wrong? So close! Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the INNER query you filter away all people, that can potentially give you `0` results.

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN job_status = 'Archived' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
  FROM typesetting 
  LEFT JOIN employees ON typesetting.employees_id = employees.id 
  LEFT JOIN job_status ON typesetting.job_status_id = job_status.id 
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY first_name ASC;
```

Comment: I just changed the = to <> for job_status <> 'Archived' as I want to exclude records that are archived. Other than that, this seems to do exactly what I want. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  first_name, COUNT(js.id)
FROM    employees e
LEFT JOIN
        typesetting ts
ON      ts.employees_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN
        job_status js
ON      js.id = ts.job_status_id
        AND js.status <> 'Archived'
GROUP BY
        first_name
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Unassigned', COUNT(*)
FROM    typesetting ts
JOIN    job_status js
ON      js.id = ts.job_status_id
        AND js.status <> 'Archived'
WHERE   ts.employees_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    employees
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your query right. You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    employees.first_name,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            typesetting
            JOIN job_status ON typesetting.job_status_id = job_status.id 
        WHERE
            typesetting.employees_id = employees.id
            AND job_status NOT LIKE 'Archived' 
    )
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY 
    first_name ASC
```